# Why am I getting ClassCastException when running Liquibase?

Tags: neo4j, liquibase, liquibase-maven-plugin, neo4j-aura

I'm trying to configure Liquibase to work with our neo4j Aura instance. The first time I run it, it   works fine, but every subsequent time I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:4.24.0:update (default) on project liquibase: 
[ERROR] Error setting up or running Liquibase:
[ERROR] java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.ZonedDateTime cannot be cast to class java.sql.Timestamp (java.time.ZonedDateTime is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; java.sql.Timestamp is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')
```

The version of liquibase and the neo4j extension is 4.24.0, the plugin configuration in maven is like this:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <changeLogFile>liquibase/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                    <url>jdbc:neo4j:neo4j+s://MYAURAURL:7687</url>
                    <driver>org.neo4j.jdbc.boltrouting.BoltRoutingNeo4jDriver</driver>
                    <username>neo4j</username>
                    <password>MYAURAPASS</password>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I'm guessing it's trying to cast these that show up in the database:
dateCreated: 2023-10-11T10:32:17.024000000Z
dateUpdated: 2023-10-11T10:33:24.253000000Z
But that isn't anything that I've defined explicitly.

I've tried running with previous versions of the liquibase plugin. It either gives the same message or doesn't run at all.

Comment: Out of interest, did you follow any particular example to configure Liquibase's execution?

Comment: I've used a previous project as a reference, although it was set up with Postgres in mind, not Neo4j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong driver.
It should be `liquibase.ext.neo4j.database.jdbc.Neo4jDriver`.
I should probably rework [the documentation section on this](https://www.neo4j.com/labs/liquibase/docs/reference-configuration/).